# AMD media foundation hardware decoders and encoders

Tags: amd-radeon, setup, video-codecs, multimedia

I use the K-lite mega codec pack. I guess AMD's are the same as k-lite, but I'm truly really unsure. Should I install it together with K-lite? Sincerely, I don't know what is it.

I have searched at AMD.com, and it doesn't come with anything. I have googled around and there's just possibly one or two direct answers about it, but they are vague enough to not consider them.

Bonus: There's another option in their setup, AMD drag and drop transcoding. How do I use this, is it worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE***: AMD removed this feature from their latest CCC setup (at the time of this update)

*Original answer:*

> I have asked and read answers on many multimedia forums, including
>   AMD.
>
> For what I have understood, these allow applications to be able to use
>   the video card's hardware acceleration when decoding and encoding.
>
> Also, it seems that programs that use the Windows Media Foundation,
>   like Windows Media Player would be able to benefit from the hardware
>   acceleration.
>
> About transcoding, Windows has the feature to convert incompatible
>   files when dragging and dropping them to a portable player that is
>   able to use this feature. It seems this helps, again, to use the video
>   card's hardware acceleration.
>
> According to the Administrator at Codecguide.com (the official home of
>   the k-lite code pack) these don't affect in any way other codec packs.